# Does a Talmid Muvhak tear Kriya for his Rebbe?

Tags: halacha, rebbe-talmid-muvhak

Gemora [Moed Katan 25a](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.25a?lang=bi) regarding tearing Kriya for a sage.  Who does and does not?  How do you define a Talmud Muvhak?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but yes that gemara is accepted in shulchan aruch yd 340 8 https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%9E_%D7%97 that a student tears for his teacher to varying degrees.

Comment: I also think you mean muvhak - מובהק

Answer (score 2):

Yes a talmud muvhak does tear for his Rebbe - Refer to [SA YD 340:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.340.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [YD 242:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.242.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). Also refer to Rambam in [Mishneh Torah , Talmud Torah 5:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Torah_Study.5.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Someone's main Rebbe is considered the one who taught him all his teaching. The Rambam cited above qualifies this as:

> וּכְשֶׁיָּמוּת רַבּוֹ קוֹרֵעַ כָּל בְּגָדָיו עַד שֶׁהוּא מְגַלֶּה אֶת לִבּוֹ וְאֵינוֹ מְאַחֶה לְעוֹלָם. בַּמֶּה דְּבָרִים אֲמוּרִים בְּרַבּוֹ מֻבְהָק **שֶׁלָּמַד מִמֶּנּוּ רֹב חָכְמָתוֹ**
>
> And when his Rebbe dies he tears all his clothes until his chest (lit. his heart) is revealed and he should never mend them (his garment). With what our these words dealing with? With his main Rebbe **who taught him most of his knowledge**.

And as the Shulchan Aruch cited about notes this means:

> על רבו שרוב חכמתו ממנו **אם מקרא מקרא ואם משנה משנה אם גמרא גמרא**
>
> For his teacher from whom he derived the greater part of his knowledge, **whether in Torah, Mishna or Gemara**.